# Tiny question about Coding conventions for Lomuto partition code

Tags: algorithms, quicksort

Just out of curiousity: Both *Introduction to Algorithms* (Cormen et al), Wikipedia, and prior cs.stackexchange questions all present the Lomuto partition as:

```
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
pivot := A[hi]
i := lo - 1    
for j := lo to hi - 1 do
    if A[j] < pivot then
        i := i + 1
        swap A[i] with A[j]
swap A[i + 1] with A[hi]
return i + 1
```

which is a bit hard to remember.  I'm wondering why the following restatement isn't used instead. Suppose we do a change of variable, with i' = i+1 and swap the two lines after "if A[j] < pivot" accordingly.  In this case we have:

```
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
pivot := A[hi]
i' := lo     
for j := lo to hi - 1 do
    if A[j] < pivot then
        swap A[i'] with A[j]
        i' := i' + 1
swap A[i'] with A[hi]
return i'
```

so then the final statement is just

```
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
pivot := A[hi]
i := lo     
for j := lo to hi - 1 do
    if A[j] < pivot then
        swap A[i] with A[j]
        i := i + 1
swap A[i] with A[hi]
return i
```

I know that this isn't a big improvement, but is there some reason that the presentations I've seen all use the original formulation?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hoares-vs-lomuto-partition-scheme-quicksort/ uses exactly your code. As far as I can see, they are really equivalent and your code is simpler.